# Why is Thread[{ a, b }] the same as Transpose[{ a, b }]?

Tags: list-manipulation

I understand the idea of both Thread and Transpose, but do not understand whatever nuance it is that makes

```
Thread[{ a, b }] == Transpose[{ a, b }]
```

Where `a` and `b` are lists. I thought Thread had to take a function.

Comment: What are `a` and `b` in your code? For undefined symbols $a$ and $b$ `Transpose` will complain that the list `{a, b}` cannot be transposed.

Comment: @MarcoB a and b are lists of values

Comment: `Transpose` applies to lists; `Thread` also to any arbitrary head. Surely you have taken a look at those documentation examples?

Comment: Look at `Thread[f[a,b]]` then `%/.f->List`.

Comment: `{a,b}` is just a shortcut for `List[a,b]`, and `Thread` then does with `List` just what it would do with any other symbol...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Brilliant, nice explanation.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `Transpose` is much more efficient.

Comment: Tyler, I wonder if you would consider turning your newfound insight into an answer for your question. Self-answers are encourages on StackExchange, and it would be an excellent way to think it all through and cement this new tidbit of information...

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Is the greater efficiency of `Transpose` deducible from first principles, or is it a timing result.  (It is unclear to me why delegation in the face of a list of lists could not address efficiency differences.)  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoB I can't answer a closed question.

Comment: @Alan `Transpose` is a more precise operation, since it is more restricted in general, works on rectangular structures only. Therefore, it seems natural to expect that it can be faster. Also, since it rearranges rectangular structures, one can make it very efficient since it maps directly to C arrays (of pointers to list parts, on elements themselves in the case of packed arrays).